# Spring @Autowired в новом потоке

Tags: java, spring

Имеется некоторый бин

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
...
}
```

Его необходимо вызывать в другом методе, который создает новые потоки:

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

new Thread(new NewClientsThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Здесь вызывается userService    
    }
})).start();
```

Но при работе в момент обращения к бину получаю NullPointerException. Я так понимаю, что в новом потоке недоступен контекст спринга.

Есть какие-то способы побороть эту проблему?

Comment: Добавьте поле UserService в NewClientsThread. И добавьте конструктор типа NewClientsThread (UserService u, Runnable target); И передавайте Ваш userService параметром в конструктор

Comment: бин не заинжектился, смотрите логи спринга на старте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замени

```
new Thread(new NewClientsThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Здесь вызывается userService    
    }
})).start();
```

на

```
new Thread(new NewClientsThread(new Runnable(){
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void run() {
         SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); 
        //далее вызывается userService    
    }
})).start();
```

Хочу заметить, что, по-моему мнению, у тебя где-то закралась архитектурная недоработка, ибо создание потоков нужно использовать в очень редких случаях.

Comment: А как можно обойтись без потоков, если нужно  параллельное исполнение нескольких процессов?

Comment: @carapuz никак. Хочу отметить что я имел ввиду именно явное создание потоков. С ними очень много проблем, включая утечки памяти и переполнения пула. Если у тебя что-то плановое, то лучше использовать планировщик и из него запускать управляющий метод бина. Если уже всё-таки надо именно ситуационные потоки, то их лучше запускать через пулы